# How to open tree-select in a dropdown menu by default

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to find a way how to make **nz-tree-select** be opened by default on dropdown menu item click.

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3fgnn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I'm trying to use **(nzVisibleChange)** event from **nz-dropdown** alongside **[(nzOpen)]** state from **nz-tree-select**. But no luck for now.
Also I have an access to **NzTreeSelectComponent**, but I'm not sure how can I use it.

```html
<button nz-button nz-dropdown [nzDropdownMenu]="menu"
      (nzVisibleChange)="dropDownVisibleChange($event)"
      nzPlacement="bottomLeft"
      nzTrigger="click">Button
</button>

<nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
  <nz-tree-select #tree [(nzOpen)]="isOpen" class="tree-select" nzNoAnimation nzShowExpand [nzMaxTagCount]="2"
    [nzNodes]="nodes" [nzHideUnMatched]="true" nzVirtualHeight="498px" [nzShowSearch]="true" nzCheckable
    nzPlaceHolder="Please select">
  </nz-tree-select>
</nz-dropdown-menu>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
  isOpen: boolean;
  @ViewChild(NzTreeSelectComponent, { static: true })
  tree: NzTreeSelectComponent;
  nodes = [
    {
      title: "parent 1",
      key: "100",
      children: [
        {
          title: "parent 1-0",
          key: "1001",
          children: [
            { title: "leaf 1-0-0", key: "10010", isLeaf: true },
            { title: "leaf 1-0-1", key: "10011", isLeaf: true }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "parent 1-1",
          key: "1002",
          children: [{ title: "leaf 1-1-0", key: "10020", isLeaf: true }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  dropDownVisibleChange(open: boolean): void {
    console.log("VisibleChange", open);
    this.isOpen = open;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.tree);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.tree);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/tree-select/tree-select.component.ts) of nz-tree-select, there are two useful public functions you can use here that will help you resolve the issue, `openDropdown` and `closeDropDown`. the `nzOpen` boolean flag won't help here because it doesn't trigger the dropdown menu.

in your component, you can make the following change:

```
dropDownVisibleChange(open: boolean): void {
    if (open) {
      setTimeout(() => this.tree.openDropdown());
    } else {
      this.tree.closeDropDown();
    }
  }
```

the result is, that when you toggle your dropdown (which hosts the tree select), you also toggle the tree select's dropdown.
The reason for the `setTimeout` is that when that event is triggered for opening, the dropdown is not yet visible.

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nz-tree-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)